# Missing shared_ref

Tags: c++, c++11, refcounting

While working with `std::shared_ptr` a lot I kind of miss a `shared_ref` implementation. That is a specialization of `shared_ptr`, which guarantees, that it never wraps a `nullptr` (given right usage, of course).
I kind of wonder why it is not in the C++11 standard. Are there any mayor problems when implementing it? On the top of my head I cannot think of any.

EDIT:

I would expect to have an interface similar to:

```
template <typename T>
class shared_ref {
public:
  shared_ref( T&& ref );
  T& get();
  T* operator&() const;

  template< class Y > 
  void reset( Y&& obj );

  long use_count() const;
  bool unique() const;

  void swap( shared_ref& r );
};
```

Comment: `shared_ptr` shouldn't be `nullptr` given right usage, either. It's not there probably because nobody thought about it, or they did and rejected it on the grounds of not being useful enough to justify adding it.

Comment: `shared_ptr` will be `nullptr` e.g. when using the default constructor.

Comment: `shared_ref` wouldn't have a default constructor, so just don't use default ctor on `shared_ptr`.

Comment: That is not the point. The point is, that if a function gets passed a `shared_ptr` there is no guarantee, that it is not null. If you really want to write correct code you would have to check for nullptr before using the ptr. Given, that 95% of all coders don't give a damn.

Comment: @LCIDFire You can't make correct code out of incorrect code.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Please elaborate, I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @LCIDFire If the function is not supposed to work with null pointers, passing a null pointer to it is a bug. Trying to fix that bug from *within* the function is not going to work, because the buggy code is outside.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, the question is how best to enforce a contract, the contract being that the pointer is not null. The earlier you catch such errors the better. The gold standard is strict type checking, where you catch the error at compile time.

Comment: @Mark sure, but you don't catch the error at compile time by checking if your arguments are nullptr. That's what I'm saying: If you want to write correct code you don't have to check for nullptr before using the pointer, you have to make it not be null in the first place.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That is exactly the reason why I want a `shared_ref`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any mayor problems when implementing it?

Here's one: you can't take ownership of a *reference*. The whole point of a smart pointer is to claim ownership of the pointer itself. `shared_ref` can't work because you can't control the lifetime of a reference.

And no, this isn't going to fly either:

```
shared_ref( T&& ref ) : p(&ref) {}
```

The user may have given you a stack variable, which now means you have "shared" ownership between this object and a stack variable. And stack variables *cannot* share ownership with something.

You can only control the lifetime of a pointer. And pointers can be NULL. Therefore, the only thing you can do is a runtime check to see if a pointer is NULL.

The absolute best you can do is an interface equivalent to `shared_ptr` except that it has no default constructor and throws in the event of being given NULL. Is that really worth creating a whole new pointer type over?

---

The C++ Core Guidelines support library has the `not_null` template, which can be applied to most pointer-like types. So you can use `not_null<shared_ptr>` when you want to verify that a pointer isn't NULL, but only once when it enters use. After the initial creating of the pointer, it doesn't need to check again.

Granted, you can't force other people to use them, but use of the type consistently will resolve the issue.

Comment: Well you are right. I would perhaps solve this by requiring `T` to have a move constructor. Then you could internally build a pointer and indeed take ownership. This kind of verbose requirement is probably the reason, why it is not in the standard library.

Comment: Also perhaps the name is wrong - perhaps `shared_obj` is probably the more correct name!?

Comment: There could still be value in having language support for non-nullable pointers (technically all pointers can be null, but compile-time checks on such a meta-type would still be possible in exactly the same way in which Swift does it).  The only two checks that'd need to be performed are: 1. Make sure there's no direct `nullptr` assignment, 2. Make sure optional pointers are unwrapped before trying to assign them to a non-optional pointers. (All this could be verified at compile-time).  PS: one could still mess with the memory, but that's on you.

Comment: @diegoreymendez: The Core C++ Guidelines support library provides the `not_null` template as a library solution. The only defect it has is that it cannot work with `unique_ptr` or another non-copyable type. And whether a pointer is null or not is a runtime property, not a compile-time one. To turn it into the latter makes certain entirely valid constructs impossible to write.

Comment: In the scenario I proposed regular nullable pointers would still exist and work in the very same way they do now (how would a new and optional feature make valid constructs impossible to write?).  And yes, currently pointers have to be checked for null at runtime (status quo).  My whole suggestion is being able to declare non-nullable pointers that can't be directly assigned `nullptr` or nullable pointers (unless you first "unwrap" them).

Comment: See the answer explaining what "unwrapping" is here - this would be perfectly feasibly in C++ too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift

Comment: @diegoreymendez: Since `not_null` exists, what reason exactly would there be to make this a *language* feature?

Comment: If `not_null<T>` does all I mentioned, then none - it'd be enough.  But I can't comment on it since it seems there's no OSX implementation yet?  Time will tell.

Comment: Re. "the absolute best" paragraph, it would also have to have different behaviour in the case of an explicit call to `reset(nullptr)`. And I don't really agree with the previous paragraph: a `shared_ptr` manages lifetime of *an object*, not of a pointer.  It might use a pointer as part of its internal representation but that's not pertinent.  Conceptually there is no problem with a container managing lifetime of a shared object without ever allowing there to be no current object being managed; but that would simply be a different class to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: "The user may have given you a stack variable, which now means you have "shared" ownership between this object and a stack variable."
Well, the user may have given your shared_ptr the address of a stack variable, which now means you have "shared" ownership between your shared_ptr and a stack variable.
shared_ptr can't prevent the user from doing this mistake, so that shared_ref can't either is not really speaking against having a shared_ref class.

Comment: @Kaiserludi: It's a lot easier to write `shared_ref(stack_variable)` than it is to write `shared_ptr(&stack_variable)`. The latter requires the user to write that `&`, which means they had to realize that they need to pass a pointer. Which makes them reconsider whether they really want to do this. That's not the case for `shared_ref`; it can just take a variable directly.

Comment: But aren't we talking about `shared_obj(std::move(stack_variable))` instead of `shared_ref(stack_variable)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways for a `shared_ptr` to be null - either it was default constructed, or it was assigned a null value at some point. Since you already agree it doesn't make sense to default construct your hypothetical `shared_ref` class, that leaves only the second condition.

If you tried to assign a `nullptr` to your `shared_ref` object, what would you expect to happen? Should it throw an error? It's trivial to do the same thing with a regular `shared_ptr` using a simple template function:

```
template<typename T>
T* notnull(T* ptr)
{
    if (ptr == std::nullptr)
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("nullptr"));
    return ptr;
}

std::shared_ptr<int> pint = notnull(GetIntPtr());
```

Generally things aren't added to the standard unless there's a compelling need with no easy workarounds.

Comment: See my edit. I would perhaps also allow overloads for pointers, but they would have to throw exceptions when finding a ptr to be null.

Comment: @LCIDFire, again I ask: what is supposed to happen when you try to assign a nullptr to this object? I.e. `T* p = nullptr; my_ref.reset(*p);`

Comment: The only real problem is that getting the ref _easier_ is a little problematic. Calling `get()` is indeed a little verbose :(

Comment: That is, like anywhere in the std library, undefined behavior. And a bug in the calling code, btw.