# What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm learning Swift for iOS 8 / OSX 10.10 by following [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2), and the term "**unwrapped value**" is used several times, as in this paragraph (under *Objects and Class*):

> When working with optional values, you can write ? before operations
> like methods, properties, and subscripting. If the value before the ?
> is nil, everything after the ? is ignored and the value of the whole
> expression is nil. Otherwise, **the optional value is unwrapped**, and
> everything after the ? acts on the **unwrapped value**. In both cases, the
> value of the whole expression is an optional value.

```
let optionalSquare: Square? = Square(sideLength: 2.5, name: "optional square") 
let sideLength = optionalSquare?.sideLength
```

I don't get it, and searched on the web without luck.

What does this means?

---

### Edit

From Cezary's answer, there's a slight difference between the output of the original code and the final solution (tested on playground) :

#### Original code

[image: Original code]

#### Cezary's solution

[image: Cezary's solution]

The superclass' properties are shown in the output in the second case, while there's an empty object in the first case.

Isn't the result supposed to be identical in both case?

**Related Q&A : [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026093/1437016)**

Comment: Cezary's answer is spot on. Also, there's a great intro book to Swift available for [FREE on iBooks](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)

Comment: @DanielStormApps This iBook is a portable version of the linked tutorial in my question :)

Answer (score 296, accepted):

First, you have to understand what an Optional type is. An optional type basically means that the variable *can be* `nil`.

Example:

```
var canBeNil : Int? = 4
canBeNil = nil
```

The question mark indicates the fact that `canBeNil` can be `nil`.

This would not work:

```
var cantBeNil : Int = 4
cantBeNil = nil // can't do this
```

To get the value from your variable if it is optional, you have to ***unwrap it***. This just means putting an exclamation point at the end.

```
var canBeNil : Int? = 4
println(canBeNil!)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
let optionalSquare: Square? = Square(sideLength: 2.5, name: "optional square") 
let sideLength = optionalSquare!.sideLength
```

A sidenote:

You can also declare optionals to automatically unwrap by using an exclamation mark instead of a question mark.

Example:

```
var canBeNil : Int! = 4
print(canBeNil) // no unwrapping needed
```

So an alternative way to fix your code is:

```
let optionalSquare: Square! = Square(sideLength: 2.5, name: "optional square") 
let sideLength = optionalSquare.sideLength
```

### EDIT:

The difference that you're seeing is exactly the symptom of the fact that the optional value is **wrapped**. There is another layer on top of it. The **unwrapped** version just shows the straight object because it is, well, unwrapped.

A quick playground comparison:

[image: playground]

In the first and second cases, the object is not being automatically unwrapped, so you see two "layers" (`{{...}}`), whereas in the third case, you see only one layer (`{...}`) because the object is being automatically unwrapped.

The difference between the first case and the second two cases is that the second two cases will give you a runtime error if `optionalSquare` is set to `nil`. Using the syntax in the first case, you can do something like this:

```
if let sideLength = optionalSquare?.sideLength {
    println("sideLength is not nil")
} else {
    println("sidelength is nil")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! The code included in my question is quoted from Apple's tutorial (link in the question), and I guess it's supposed to work as-is (and it does). Though, your final solution and the original one outputs different results (see my edit). Any thought?

Comment: Cool. Great explanation. I'm still confused, though. Why would I want to use an optional value? When is it useful? Why did Apple create this behavior and syntax?

Comment: It is particularly relevant when it comes to class properties. Swift requires all non-optional methods to be initialized in the `init()` function of the class. I recommend reading the chapters "The Basics" (covers optionals), "Initialization", and "Optional Chaining" in the Swift book released by Apple.

Comment: @ToddLehman Apple created this to help you write much safer code. E.g. imagine all the null pointer exceptions in Java crashing a program because somebody forgot to check for null. Or weird behaviour on Objective-C because you forgot to check for nil. With Optional type you can't forget to deal with nil. The compiler forces you to deal with it.

Comment: @AdamSmith — Coming from a Java background, I can definitely see the use of the optionals... but coming also (more recently) from an Objective-C background, I'm still having trouble seeing the use of it, because Objective-C explicitly allows you to send messages to nil objects. Hmm. I'd love to see someone write up an example of these showing how they help make code shorter and safer than the equivalent code that doesn't use them. I'm not saying they're not useful; I'm just saying I don't yet "get it."

Comment: @ToddLehman Simplest example would be `str.integerValue` that might not succeed. Then you get 0. But you can't distinguish that from the string "0". Hence you fail to catch an important error. In Swift `str.integerValue` would return a value of type `Int?` and you can't use this in place of an  Int. `if let num: Int = str.integerValue { dostuff(num) }` must be used to retrieve the int value if it exists. `destuff(num)` will not be called if `integerValue` fails. `let num: Int = str.integerValue` doesn't work.

Comment: @AdamSmith — Ah yes. I see. Thank you. So writing `if let num: Int = str.integerValue { dostuff(num) }` is a different way of writing `if (str != nil) { dostuff(str.integerValue) }`. Hmm...that might take a bit of getting used to.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed! I have one final incomprehension though. If that third case exists, why would I use the second one at all? Is there a specific scenario where I would need to use the second case over the third one?

Comment: @ToddLehman Also, optionals work with primitive values (ints, structs, etc) giving more flexibility than ObjC's nil.

Comment: [matteo](http://matteomanferdini.com/the-complete-guide-to-understanding-swift-optionals/)  explains in depth the Optionals with many simple examples. Give it a try.

Comment: more narrative explanation (I liked more [here](http://matteomanferdini.com/the-complete-guide-to-understanding-swift-optionals/))

Comment: @CezaryWojcik thanks for the explanation. But, any idea when to use "optional" and when to use "unwrap" ? I really get confused between this two.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik, what you do is called a forced unwrapping. That's not the recommended way of unwrapping an optional variable.
An example to unwrap the correct way would be:
if let unwrappedVar = optSquare {
    print(optSquare.someMethod
} else {
   //do whatever to handle nil
}

Comment: @ToddLehman Also, more practically, the requirement for explicit optionals in Swift (as opposed to implicit optionals in Objective-C, which fail silently when a message is sent to nil) was added for performance and optimization reasons. Objective-C has some optimization shortcomings due to its dynamic and ambiguously-typed nature, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014045/does-swift-have-dynamic-dispatch-and-virtual-methods. Swift's optionals allow the compiler to do some work to avoid much of the dynamic dispatching that is characteristic of Objective-C.

Comment: one more thing, inside the **if** you don’t need to use ? or ! anymore. **if let sideLength = optionalSquare.sideLength** is fine

Comment: XCode should use syntax highlighting to change the color or text style of optional variables so you know if you need to unwrap. So like a variable would show as underlined until you unwrap it

Comment: Good detailed explanation. Moreover for basic and concise explanation i recommend to see Apple Docs on optional chaining: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 17):

The existing correct answer is great, but I found that for me to understand this fully, I needed a good analogy, since this is a very abstract and weird concept.

So, let me help those fellow "right-brained" (visual thinking) developers out by giving a different perspective in addition to the correct answer. Here is a good analogy that helped me a lot.

**Birthday Present Wrapping Analogy**

Think of optionals as being like birthday presents that come in stiff, hard, colored wrapping.

You don't know if there's anything inside the wrapping until you unwrap the present — maybe there is nothing at all inside! If there is something inside, it could be yet another present, which is also wrapped, and which also *might contain nothing*. You might even unwrap 100 nested presents to finally discover there was *nothing but wrapping*.

If the value of the optional is not `nil`, now you have revealed a box containing *something*. But, especially if the value is not explicitly typed and is a variable and not a predefined constant, then you may still need to *open the box* before you can know anything specific about what's in the box, like *what type* it is, or what the actual *value* is.

***What's In The Box?!* Analogy**

Even after you unwrap the variable, you are still like Brad Pitt in the [last scene in SE7EN](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1giVzxyoclE) (*warning*: spoilers and very R-rated foul language and violence), because even after you have unwrapped the present, you are in the following situation: **you now have `nil`, or a box containing *something* (but you don't know what).**

You might know the type of the *something*. For example, if you declared the variable as being type, `[Int:Any?]`, then you'd know you had a (potentially empty) Dictionary with integer subscripts that yield wrapped contents of any old type.

That is why dealing with collection types (Dictionaries and Arrays) in Swift can get kind of hairy.

Case in point:

```
typealias presentType = [Int:Any?]

func wrap(i:Int, gift:Any?) -> presentType? {
    if(i != 0) {
        let box : presentType = [i:wrap(i-1,gift:gift)]
        return box
    }
    else {
        let box = [i:gift]
        return box
    }
}

func getGift() -> String? {
    return "foobar"
}

let f00 = wrap(10,gift:getGift())

//Now we have to unwrap f00, unwrap its entry, then force cast it into the type we hope it is, and then repeat this in nested fashion until we get to the final value.

var b4r = (((((((((((f00![10]! as! [Int:Any?])[9]! as! [Int:Any?])[8]! as! [Int:Any?])[7]! as! [Int:Any?])[6]! as! [Int:Any?])[5]! as! [Int:Any?])[4]! as! [Int:Any?])[3]! as! [Int:Any?])[2]! as! [Int:Any?])[1]! as! [Int:Any?])[0])

//Now we have to DOUBLE UNWRAP the final value (because, remember, getGift returns an optional) AND force cast it to the type we hope it is

let asdf : String = b4r!! as! String

print(asdf)
```

Comment: nice      

Comment: love the analogy! so, is there a better way to unwrap the boxes then? in your code example

Comment: Schrödinger's cat is in the box

Comment: Thanks for confusing me.... 
What kind of programmer gives a Birthday Present that's empty anyways?   kinda mean

Comment: @Jacksonkr Or not.

Answer (score 14):

Swift places a high premium on type safety. The entire Swift language was designed with safety in mind. It is one of the hallmarks of Swift and one that you should welcome with open arms. It will assist in the development of clean, readable code and help keep your application from crashing.

All optionals in Swift are demarcated with the `?` symbol. By setting the `?` after the name of the type in which you are declaring as optional you are essentially *casting* this not as the type in which is before the `?`, but instead as the *optional* type.

---

> Note: A variable or type `Int` is **not** the same as `Int?`. They are two different types that can not be operated on each other.

---

**Using Optional**

```
var myString: String?

myString = "foobar"
```

This does **not** mean that you are working with a type of `String`. This means that you are working with a type of `String?` (String Optional, or Optional String). In fact, whenever you attempt to

```
print(myString)
```

at runtime, the debug console will print `Optional("foobar")`. The "`Optional()`" part indicates that this variable may or may not have a value at runtime, but just so happens to currently be containing the string "foobar". This "`Optional()`" indication will remain unless you do what is called "unwrapping" the optional value.

**Unwrapping** an optional means that you are now casting that type as non-optional. This will generate a new type and assign the value that resided within that optional to the new non-optional type. This way you can perform operations on that variable as it has been guaranteed by the compiler to have a solid value.

---

**Conditionally Unwrapping** will check if the value in the optional is `nil` or not. If it is not `nil`, there will be a newly created constant variable that will be assigned the value and *unwrapped* into the non-optional constant. And from there you may safely use the non-optional in the `if` block.

> Note: You can give your conditionally unwrapped constant the same name as the optional variable you are unwrapping.

```
if let myString = myString {
    print(myString)
    // will print "foobar"
}
```

Conditionally unwrapping optionals is the cleanest way to access an optional's value because if it contains a nil value then everything within the if let block will not execute. Of course, like any if statement, you may include an else block

```
if let myString = myString {
    print(myString)
    // will print "foobar"
}
else {
    print("No value")
}
```

---

**Forcibly Unwrapping** is done by employing what is known as the `!` ("bang") operator. This is less safe but still allows your code to compile. However whenever you use the bang operator you must be 1000% certain that your variable does in fact contain a solid value before forcibly unwrapping.

```
var myString: String?

myString = "foobar"

print(myString!)
```

This above is entirely valid Swift code. It prints out the value of `myString` that was set as "foobar". The user would see `foobar` printed in the console and that's about it. But let's assume the value was never set:

```
var myString: String?

print(myString!)
```

Now we have a different situation on our hands. Unlike Objective-C, whenever an attempt is made to forcibly unwrap an optional, and the optional has not been set and is `nil`, when you try to unwrap the optional to see what's inside your application will crash.

---

**Unwrapping w/ Type Casting**. As we said earlier that while you are `unwrapping` the optional you are actually casting to a non-optional type, you can also cast the non-optional to a different type. For example:

```
var something: Any?
```

Somewhere in our code the variable `something` will get set with some value. Maybe we are using generics or maybe there is some other logic that is going on that will cause this to change. So later in our code we want to use `something` but still be able to treat it differently if it is a different type. In this case you will want to use the `as` keyword to determine this:

> Note: The `as` operator is how you type cast in Swift.

```
// Conditionally
if let thing = something as? Int {
    print(thing) // 0
}

// Optionally
let thing = something as? Int
print(thing) // Optional(0)

// Forcibly
let thing = something as! Int
print(thing) // 0, if no exception is raised
```

Notice the difference between the two `as` keywords. Like before when we forcibly unwrapped an optional we used the `!` bang operator to do so. Here you will do the same thing but instead of casting as just a non-optional you are casting it also as `Int`. And it *must* be able to be downcast as `Int`, otherwise, like using the bang operator when the value is `nil` your application will crash.

And in order to use these variables at all in some sort or mathematical operation they must be unwrapped in order to do so.

For instance, in Swift only valid number data types of the same kind may be operated on each other. When you cast a type with the `as!` you are forcing the downcast of that variable as though you are ***certain*** it is of that type, therefore safe to operate on and not crash your application. This is ok as long as the variable indeed is of the type you are casting it to, otherwise you'll have a mess on your hands.

Nonetheless casting with `as!` will allow your code to compile. By casting with an `as?` is a different story. In fact, `as?` declares your `Int` as a completely different data type all together.

**Now it is `Optional(0)`**

And if you ever tried to do your homework writing something like

```
1 + Optional(1) = 2
```

Your math teacher would have likely given you an "F". Same with Swift. Except Swift would rather not compile at all rather than give you a grade. **Because at the end of the day the optional may in fact be nil**.

Safety First Kids.

Comment: Nice explanation of the optional types. Helped clear things up for me.

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

'?' means optional chaining expression 
the'!'means is force-value  
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 ways to unwrapping optional value in Swift.

1. Optional Binding - Safe
2. Optional Chaining - Safe
3. Optional Pattern - Safe
4. Nil Coalescing - Safe
5. Guard Statement - Safe
6. Force Unwrapping - Unsafe
7. Implicit Unwrapping - Unsafe