# PFUser not unwrapped - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm beginning to learn swift with parse and i've run into this error:

"Value of optional type 'PFUser?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'

I can't seem to get it to work...

```
        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile",
        "user_about_me", "user_birthday"], block: {
            user, error in

            if user == nil {
                println("the user canceled fb login")
                //add uialert

                return

            }
                //new user
            else if user.isNew {
                println("user singed up through FB")

                //get information from fb then save to parse
                FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me?fields=picture,first_name,birthday,gender",  completionHandler: {
                    connection, result, error in
                    //print results
                    println(result)
                    //result dictionary about user
                    var r = result as NSDictionary
                    //prnt dictionary
                    println(NSDictionary)
                    //match parse column with what fb sends
                    user["firstName"] = r["first_name"]
                    user["gender"] = r["gender"]
                    //r = result, then key into using picture.  Then key into url using the data
                 let pictureURL = ((r["picture"] as NSDictionary)["data"] as NSDictionary) ["url"] as String
```

Comment: Just write ! after every `user` usage, if you are sure it is not nil

Comment: What if i'm not sure that it's nil, that's the thing i don't get..

Comment: I highly suggest to not get in the habit of force unwrapping things in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is explanation: [What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile",
    "user_about_me", "user_birthday"], block: {
        user, error in

        if user == nil {
            println("the user canceled fb login")
            //add uialert

            return

        }
            //new user
        else if user!.isNew {
            println("user singed up through FB")

            //get information from fb then save to parse
            FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me?fields=picture,first_name,birthday,gender",  completionHandler: {
                connection, result, error in
                //print results
                println(result)
                //result dictionary about user
                var r = result as NSDictionary
                //prnt dictionary
                println(NSDictionary)
                //match parse column with what fb sends
                user["firstName"] = r["first_name"]
                user["gender"] = r["gender"]
                //r = result, then key into using picture.  Then key into url using the data
             let pictureURL = ((r["picture"] as NSDictionary)["data"] as NSDictionary) ["url"] as String
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using if `user == nil {...` you should really use

```
    if let user = user { 
       // Login succeeded...
    } 
    else { 
       // Login failed
    }
```

The variable `user` will then be unwrapped inside the `if let` and you can continue using `user` the same way you are.