# Convert optional string to int in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I am having troubles while converting optional string to int.

```
   println("str_VAR = \(str_VAR)")      
   println(str_VAR.toInt())
```

Result is

```
   str_VAR = Optional(100)
   nil
```

And i want it to be

```
   str_VAR = Optional(100)
   100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unwrap it this way:

```
if let yourStr = str_VAR?.toInt() {
    println("str_VAR = \(yourStr)")  //"str_VAR = 100" 
    println(yourStr)                 //"100"

}
```

Refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift) for more info.

**When to use “if let”?**

`if let` is a special structure in Swift that allows you to check if an Optional holds a value, and in case it does – do something with the unwrapped value. Let’s have a look:

```
if let yourStr = str_VAR?.toInt() {
    println("str_VAR = \(yourStr)")
    println(yourStr)

}else {
    //show an alert for something else
}
```

The if let structure unwraps `str_VAR?.toInt()` (i.e. checks if there’s a value stored and takes that value) and stores its value in the `yourStr` constant. You can use `yourStr` inside the first branch of the if. Notice that inside the if you don’t need to use ? or ! anymore. It’s important to realise that`yourStr` is actually of type `Int` that’s not an Optional type so you can use its value directly.

Comment: What am I missing? Swift is telling me "Value of type String has no member toint"

Comment: @TahoeWolverine `toInt()` is no longer available.

Answer (score 16):

At the time of writing, the other answers on this page used old Swift syntax. This is an update.

## Convert Optional String to Int: `String? -> Int`

```
let optionalString: String? = "100"
if let string = optionalString, let myInt = Int(string) {
     print("Int : \(myInt)")
}
```

This converts the string `"100"` into the integer `100` and prints the output. If `optionalString` were `nil`, `hello`, or `3.5`, nothing would be printed.

Also consider using a [`guard` statement](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/).

Comment: do you know why this construct results in nil? let optionalString: String? = "100" , let newVal = Int(optionalString!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if let i = str_VAR?.toInt() {
    println("\(i)")
}
```