# value is not nil but getting unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I am trying to send some data from an array to an other interfaceController. The problem is that I am getting

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value exception

even though the array is not nil. In fact I can even print the result using

print(...).

the problem is that I cannt set this result to a label without getting the exception.

Here is my code to laugh the new interfaceController with context data

```
@IBAction func lauchInterfaceClick() {

    presentControllerWithName("SecondInterface", context: ["hi","how are you"])

}
```

And then retrieve the results in SecondInterface like below

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    if context != nil{

        let somevalue = context as! [String]

        // here is where I getting the exception, in addition to Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
        self.showWat.setText(String(somevalue[0]))

        // I have also tried this
        // self.showWat.setText(somevalue[0])

    }
```

please note that on the other hand a `print(String(somevalue[0]))` outputs `hi`

Comment: try printing `somevalue `

Comment: there are a million questions here on SO about this error, are you sure none of them offer you a solution?

Comment: You're getting the error because `showWat` is nil, not the array.

Comment: @aaisataev showWat is a WKInterfaceLabel,

Comment: @CihanTek how is it possible? showWat is a WKInterfaceLabel.. How could I fix it then

Comment: @originaluser2 unfortunately I haven' t one where even though the value is there there is still an error.. all of them are more or less similar.. in their case the value passed is nil but in my case this value is not nil

Comment: sorry guys ..I found out that I disconnected the wkInterfaceLabel to the label in the interfaceController...

Answer (score 0):

I would use an implementation of `awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?)` like this:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    if context != nil{

        let somevalue = context as? [String] {
            if somevalue.count > 0 {
                let text = somevalue[0]
                showWat.setText(text)
            }


        } else {

            // Unwrapped optional is nil
            print("someValue is nil!")
        }

    }
}
```

Checkout the section 'Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping' in the [Swift Programming Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Or checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift) here on Stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, so what results did you get? Can you confirm which object is nil? I would guess that showWat is nil.

Comment: I got the same exception. However when I assign the value directly like self.showWat.setText("hi"), it works perfectly

Comment: if somevalue.count > 0 {
            let text = somevalue[0]
            showWat.setText(text)
Then try:            
            if showWat != nil {
                showWat.setText(text)
            }
        }

Comment: You need to find what optional is nil.

Comment: sorry guys ..I just found out that I disconnected the wkInterfaceLabel to the label in the interfaceController... I think that was the problem