# Type objectId to Parse Cloud Code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to pass some parameters to my Parse Cloud Code function, and receive the following error message in Xcode. `cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' in coercion`. It works fine until I reference the `incomingUser.objectId`. Here's the code I'm passing:

```
let params = ["userType" : userType, "recipient" : self.incomingUser.objectId]

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("pushNotification", withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    (res: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      print(res)
      print(error)
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `params as [NSObject: AnyObject?]` instead.

Or if the API require `[NSObject: AnyObject]`, you would have to unwrap the `objectId` first.

```
guard let objectId = self.incomingUser.objectId else { return }
```

And then do

```
let params = ["userType" : userType, "recipient" : objectId]

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("pushNotification", withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
(res: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print(res)
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: The guard statement worked for this. Would you mind explaining why the "unwrapping" is required? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I would recommend [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift) answer for reference. I'm not quite good at explaining things in English:P. But let me know if you have any other puzzle after reading the above answer.