# Core Motion: Value of optional type 'NSOperationQueue?' not unwrapped

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

I am following a tutorial from RayWenderLich's website, however, I am stuck on the part about Core Motion.

```
// CoreMotion
    // 1
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
    // 2
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
        (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
        // 3
        let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
        // 4
        self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25)
    })
```

I try fixing the error, but I end up with more errors.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24034551/620197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSOperationQueue`'s `currentQueue` returns an optional so you need to unwrap the optional, `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!`.

```
// CoreMotion
// 1
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
// 2
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {
    (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) in
    // 3
    let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
    // 4
    self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25)
})
```

Also, the closure that you use as handler has wrong parameter types. It's `typealias CMAccelerometerHandler = (CMAccelerometerData?, NSError?) -> Void`

Comment: I tried to do that, but I end up getting an error which says: "Cannot convert value of type '(CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> ()'

Comment: So, you have two problems. One with unwrapping an optional and one with the types of parameters of the withHandler closure.

Comment: I used the version you had before you edited it. Your edited version worked out, thanks for the help!