# What are '!' and '?' marks used for in Swift

Tags: swift2, optional-chaining

When I changed from `Objective-C` to `Swift` programming, I have come across '`!`' (exclamation mark) and '`?`' (question mark) that often have to be put right after a `property`, a `method` call etc. What are these marks used for, and what happens if we did not use them?

I searched for a *thorough* answer on the web but could not find any. So I decided to put here my answer in case for anyone is in search of a clear answer for that.

I also included in my answer below a link to a question that is similar to mine, where you can find further explanation on how and where you can use these marks (i.e. '!' and '?'). My question asks and my answer explains at a more basic level than the similar question in the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

Comment: @Bhavin Yes it is similar, that's why I provided a link to the accepted answer of that question in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology used for these marks is `Optional Chaining`. They are generally used for distinguishing the cases, for example, whether a `property` is, a `method call` returns `nil`.

An example explained in [Apple's language guide for `Optional Chaining`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) is a good one to show the purpose of their use:

> First, two classes called `Person` and `Residence` are defined:
>
> ```
> class Person {
>     var residence: Residence?
> }
>
> class Residence {
>     var numberOfRooms = 1
> } Residence instances have a single `Int` property called `numberOfRooms`, with a default value of **1**. `Person` instances
> ```
>
> have an optional `residence` property of type `Residence`?.
>
> If you create a new `Person` instance, its `residence` property is
>   default initialized to `nil`, by virtue of being optional. In the code
>   below, `john` has a `residence` property value of `nil`:
>
> ```
> let john = Person()
> ```
>
> If you try to access the `numberOfRooms` property of this person’s
>   `residence`, by placing an **exclamation mark** after `residence` to
>   force the unwrapping of its value, you trigger a **runtime error**,
>   because there is no `residence` value to unwrap:
>
> ```
> let roomCount = john.residence!.numberOfRooms
> // this triggers a runtime error
> ```
>
> The code above succeeds when `john.residence` has a *non-nil* value
>   and will set `roomCount` to an `Int` value containing the appropriate
>   number of rooms. However, this code always triggers a **runtime
>   error** when `residence` is `nil`, as illustrated above.
>
> Optional chaining provides an alternative way to access the value of
>   `numberOfRooms`. To use *optional chaining*, use a question mark in
>   place of the exclamation mark:
>
> ```
> if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
>     print("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
> } else {
>     print("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
> }
> // Prints "Unable to retrieve the number of rooms."
> ```
>
> This tells Swift to “**chain**” on the optional `residence` property
>   and to retrieve the value of `numberOfRooms` if `residence` exists.
>
> Because the attempt to access `numberOfRooms` has the potential to
>   fail, the optional chaining attempt returns a value of type `Int?`, or
>   “**optional Int**”. When `residence` is `nil`, as in the example
>   above, this optional `Int` will also be `nil`, to reflect the fact
>   that it was not possible to access `numberOfRooms`. The optional `Int`
>   is accessed through optional binding to unwrap the integer and assign
>   the nonoptional value to the `roomCount` variable.
>
> Note that this is true even though `numberOfRooms` is a *nonoptional*
>   `Int`. The fact that it is queried through an optional chain means
>   that the call to `numberOfRooms` will always return an `Int?` instead
>   of an `Int`.
>
> You can assign a `Residence` instance to `john.residence`, so that it
>   no longer has a `nil` value:
>
> ```
> john.residence = Residence()
> ```

Besides the general overview of Optional Chaining above, you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034551/4369441) in StackOverflow.

Hope this gives you some perspective on Optional Chaining.

Answer (score 1):

In simpler terms adding a

```
!
```

means you are 100% guaranteed to give a value....if you add a "!" and don't give a value the app will crash saying returned a value that is nil (or something like that).....

```
?
```

means you might return a value...this is the better way of doing things if you can help it...