# Check if a String Contains Another String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filtering

I've searched pretty thoroughly to no avail. I can't quite figure out why this statement isn't working. I'm trying to filter objects where the truckVIN contains the srchString.

Is this statement actually checking "Optional(..." instead of just "hl3"?

I appreciate the help!

```
let truckVIN = item.valueForKey(x.type.uppercaseString) as! String
let srchString = x.name

if srchString.characters.count < truckVIN.characters.count {
    if truckVIN.uppercaseString.containsString(srchString.uppercaseString) {
         repeatFilTrucks.append(item)
    }
}
```

[image: Case where both if's should = true]

Comment: Unwrap the optional string before comparing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift

Comment: @jal When I insert an "!" after x.name, it tells me that I "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'"

Comment: Found the issue elsewhere in my code, you were right @Jal. Thanks!

Comment: Optional are one of the fundamentals of Swift. I *strongly* recommend you read through the introductory docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html