# SWIFT: Why do we have to put exclamation point for: str.characters.index(of: " ")!

Tags: swift

Why do we have to put exclamation point when I create, in this case, a range?

Example:

```
var str = "joe satriani"
var range = str.startIndex..<str.characters.index(of: " ")!
```

If I don't put it I get an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

Comment: Read about Optionals in Swift

Answer (score 0):

There might not be an index of `" "` if there is no space in the string, therefore returning `nil`.

```
var str = "stringwithnospaces"
var range = str.startIndex..<str.characters.index(of: " ") // nil
```