# Remove optional from string getting from NSNotification

Tags: ios, string, swift4, option-type

I m getting a string from NSNotification,but facing issue of optional keyword attached with the given string,wants to remove OPTIONAL keyword from string,here is my code:

```
func getAlertMsg(notification:NSNotification!){
        if let strAlert = notification?.object.debugDescription{
            print(strAlert)
            Helper .showAsAlert(strMessage: strAlert, VC: self)
        }
    }
```

Response

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "User created",
"user_detail":{}
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the result is, and what you want?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to **send** a non-optional string? And why is the parameter IUO?

Comment: Use non optional var, or learn how to "unwrap optional" (that's the key words to search) in Swift (that's quite basic and very useful knowledge).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

Comment: @Larme he clearly unwrapped it - `if let strAlert = ...`

Comment: The `notification.object` is optional `Any`. What object are you sending? and why are you using it's `debugDescription`?

Comment: @Zaphod: result is Optional(My Alert) and i want to remove Optional keyword

Comment: @mag_zbc The string in `debugDescription` can already contain literal `”Optional(”`

Comment: @staticVoidMan: I m sending a string from one class to other and in order to get that string from notification object im using debugDescription

Comment: Show the code where you create the string in the first place.

Comment: @priyanshu We're getting somewhere. Show how are you sending the string

Comment: getting from JSON response:                                                              let strMessage = responseVal .value(forKey: "message") as? String NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "RegAlertMsg"), object: strMessage!)

Comment: @priyanshu much more code is needed. What is `responseVal`, how is it created? And don't post code in comments, edit the original question

Comment: check edited ques

Comment: use ! to force unwrapping string value. And make sure that data type of that key is String

Comment: @mag_zbc :Have u checked?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your current code. It should be:

```
func getAlertMsg(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let string = notification.object as? String {
        Helper.showAsAlert(strMessage: string, VC: self)
    }
}
```

Also, your notification post should be:

```
let strMessage = responseVal.value(forKey: "message") as? String
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "RegAlertMsg"), 
                                object: strMessage)
```

Just pass `strMessage`. Don't bang (!) it or you app will crash when `responseVal.value(forKey: "message") as? String` fails.

Comment: He already uses optional chaining to unwrap the string - `if let strAlert = ...`

Comment: @mag_zbc But the optional chaining is done at the wrong place.

Comment: @mag_zbc Anyways, i've updated my answer. But `object` in a `NSNotification` is the final optional one. He just confused everyone by using `NSNotification!` and then `notification?.object.debugDescription`.

Comment: @priyanshu does this answer work for you because I might delete it if it's not of any help

Comment: @staticVoidMan: Hi,it helps actually and what i was using debugDescription which gives me optional so i have used only notification?.object.By the way Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @priyanshu My pleasure :)

Answer (score -3):

I have Accessed Object From Notification Like This :

@objc func updateActivityDetailWithUserEvent(notification: NSNotification){
        //do stuff

```
    print("notification obj is ",notification)

    let activityData:[String: ActivityFeed] = notification.object  as! [String: ActivityFeed]
    activityObj = activityData ["activityUpdated"]!
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    //Update UI From Main Thread
        self.setUpdatedCell()


    }

}
```

// Way to Post Notification and Passing Dictionary as Parameter :

Call It from Your method from where you like to post Notification with Dictionary parameter:

let activityData:[String: ActivityFeed] = ["activityUpdated": activityFeedObj]

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "activityUpdated"), object: activityData)
```

Here I am taking Dictionary Object from Notification that i have passed for while generation NSNotification, you can follow similar approach for Getting String Value

Comment: Too bad I can only use one downvote for that force-unwrapping

Comment: i have added sample just to give u idea about how i have access object from notification , you can change it as per your requirements.