# Checking if array is nil or not

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a array of my custom model, and I want to check if it is not nil and its size is greater then 0.

Following is my array with custom object

> `var listCountries : [Countries]? = nil`

now In viewDIdLoad I want to make a check on it. I am new to Swift. I have good experience in working in Java.

I have read out Optional values concept and guard, if let statements. But I am unable to understand how efficiently they may be used. I have read too much  SO questions but failed to figure out.

for example , if I want to check the upper given array in java I have only to do

```
if(listCountries != null && listCountries.size()>0){
    //DO something 
}
```

So to summarize my question:

1. How to make the upper given(Java code)  check in to swift 4.? What is more smooth and reliable way.
2. What is a use of if let , guard, guard let statements. if I declare a variable (array, string) as optional I have to bear optional check like force wrapping each and every place. This is for me so making too much confusion.

Please help. I know this question has been asked in different ways. But this has some different context.

Comment: Consider to declare the array as non-optional empty `var listCountries = [Countries]()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift

Comment: Check out the duplicate.  It provides 9 ways of doing this; one for every taste!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `??`.

```
if !(listCountries ?? []).isEmpty {
```

However, since you want to probably use `listCountries` in the `if` block, you should unwrap

```
if let listCountries = self.listCountries, !listCountries.isEmpty {
```

Ideally, if `nil` and empty means the same to you, don't even use an optional:

```
var listCountries: [Countries] = []
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do it something like...

```
if let list = listCountries, !list.isEmpty { // Can also use list.count > 0
    // do something
}
```

Even though you are not using the `list` inside the braces you are still using the list in the condition.

Or, like Sulthan said... make it non-optional to begin with if it makes no difference.

Comment: Again, you're the first :D

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, I would assume that you are able to recognize the difference between `nil` array and empty array.

So, if we tried to implement a literal translation to your question:

> I want to check if it is not nil and its size is greater then 0

For the first condition:

```
// "I want to check if it is not nil":
if let unwrappedList = listCountries {
    // ...
}
```

and for the second condition:

```
// "I want to check if it is not nil":
if let unwrappedList = listCountries {
    // "and its size is greater then 0":
    if !unwrappedList.isEmpty {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, you could combine both of the conditions by using the comma to achieve the multi-clause condition:

```
// I want to check if it is not nil and its size is greater then 0
if let unwrappedList = listCountries, !unwrappedList.isEmpty {
    // ...
}
```

Or by using `guard` statement:

```
// I want to check if it is not nil and its size is greater then 0
guard let unwrappedList = listCountries, !unwrappedList.isEmpty else {
    return
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if let list = listCountries {
    if(!list.isEmpty && list.count > 0) {
            //value   
        }
}
```

Comment: Both conditions are redundant.

Comment: list countries is optional you can't do that before unwrap

Comment: @U.Benlice; @vadian Thank you for pointing me out.