# Get String value from an optional in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am new to Swift and am trying to compare my Error description name with different String constants to show the user different results, based on the error.

I am using:

```
let errorName = errors.first?["name"].debugDescription
```

The value of errorName comes as "Optional(AlreadyActiveUser)" and when i compare this to my constant string "AlreadyActiveUser", i get false.

I have tried many things, but i am not able to get the value of the string inside the optional.

Someone, please help.

Comment: You need to learn about "unwrapping". That's the key word of the concept you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "unwrapped value" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional binding in this case...

```
guard let errorName = errors.first?["name"].debugDescription as? String {

    print("value is not present...")
    return
}

print(errorName)
//here you can compare errorName == "AlreadyActiveUser"
```

Comment: Compiler warning: “Conditional downcast from 'String?' to 'String' does nothing”

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
if let errorName = errors.first?["name"] as? String {

 print(errorName)
//here you can compare errorName == "AlreadyActiveUser"

}
else
{
       print("value is not present...")
}
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer, but *explaining* it would make it even better! – Why does OP's code not work, but your's does?

Comment: because .debugDescription returns string and you are wrapping it again and i am not doing it so

Answer (score 0):

try `let errorName = errors.first!["name"].debugDescription`

Notes that I forced wrapping `first` with `!` instead of `?`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this will crash your app if the errors array is empty because it doesn't contain any element to have a first. So, it's better to use a guard statement of an if statement to assure that your app won't crash,